# In Intellij is there a way to deal with shortcut key conflicts between Java and Ruby?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to do an **Extract class** in Java, and would like to use the same shortcut for **Extract Module** in Ruby, since conceptually they are similar refactorings and there is no chance for conflict.

But IntelliJ seems to ignore one of the two shortcuts, even though the action is context-specific.  Is there a way around this or is there a reason IntelliJ does this?  I will run out of shortcut keys if I can't "overload" shortcuts depending on the language I'm working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to deal with it, feel free to [file an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA), at the moment shortcuts can't be shared between these actions.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm trying to get used to IntelliJ.